# Django How to use filter when the column database has strings and foreign key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-rest-framework

I have class named `Person`, and `Person` have a attribute named `car`. In the past `car` was an string attribute. Now, my desire is to change `car` to a FK, since I've create a class named `Car`. I addition, I have the following filter:

```py
class PersonFilterHeatmapSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = {
            'car': ['exact'],
        }
```

how can I make these changes without broken my filter? Since currently my column database is populated with string values instead FK's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the `Car` model will have a `name` attribute.

Use custom function in migrations file using `migrations.RunPython` to populate the newly created FK base model with the string names.

More info can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython

And for filter use: `car__name: ['exact']`